# Reduce subordinate clauses to adjectives/ adjective phrases?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> (1) If subordinating clauses contain adjectives or adjective phrases, like
>   these below, how do you reduce them? Do you reduce them to adjectives/ adjective phrases or something?

I think the 1c and 2c are grammatically correct; but, the rest, I'm not sure...

> ... (2) Which ones of the below reduced sentences do you think are suitable in
>   formal writing?

---

### 1. Because he was late for a meeting, he ran up the stairs very fast

→1a. **Because late** for a meeting, he ran up the stairs very fast (?)

→1b. **Late** for a meeting, he ran up the stairs very fast (?)

→1c. **Being late** for a meeting, he ran up the stairs very fast (✓)

### 2. Because she was sick, she went to see a doctor.

→2a. **Because sick**, she went to see a doctor (?)

→2b. **Sick**, she went to see a doctor (?)

→2c. **Being sick**, she went to see a doctor (✓)

Comment: The versions without *because* have a completely different meaning. (And those with *because* are very awkwardly phrased, although understandable.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Though they have different meanings from the original sentences, Do you think the 1b, 2b, 1c and 2c are grammatically correct and Are they suitable for formal writing?

Comment: They're grammatical (although if that's all you're asking, that's a proofreading question). But what's *formal* is mainly a matter of opinion.